# Forcing row to the top of query result that is using an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a ListBox that's being populated by a SQL query using this statement:

```
SELECT '-1' as [Value], 'All' as [Text] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT user_id AS [Value], user_L_name AS [Text] 
FROM [issue]
Order by [Text]
```

I'm trying to alphabetize all the records after "All" while keeping "All" at the top.

If I have my ORDER BY clause like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Text] = '-1' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid column name 'Text'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What version of sql-server is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a sub-query.  I'm also assuming you meant to check if [Text] was "All" rather than "-1"

```
SELECT  [Value], [Text]
FROM
(
    SELECT '-1' as [Value], 'All' as [Text] 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id AS [Value], user_L_name AS [Text] 
    FROM [issue]
) A
Order by Case When [Text] = 'All' Then 0 Else 1 End, [Text]
```

Alternatively, you can `Order By` the [Value]:

```
Order by Case When [Value] = '-1' Then 0 Else 1 End, [Text]
```